# jenkins declarative pipeline ignoring changelog of jenkinsfiles

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline, changelog

I have apps and their codes on git repositories. Also jenkinsfiles for building apps and these files on another repository. The problem is jenkins builds changelog. Jenkins add jenkinsfiles changelog to build changesets and I don't want to that. Because these changes are according to infrastructure not relevant with apps. How to prevent this? I didn't find any workaround or solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got well your question... I don't think you can remove Jenkinsfile changes from the change set that Jenkins reads from git, but instead, you can skip your pipeline to build if there are only changes on Jenkinsfile.

If it helps...
First place, you need to read the change set:

```
    def changedFiles = []
    for (changeLogSet in currentBuild.changeSets) { 
        for (entry in changeLogSet.getItems()) { 
            for (file in entry.getAffectedFiles()) {
                changedFiles.add(file.getPath())
            }
        }
    }
```

Then, you can check if it is only Jenkinsfile:

```
if (changedFiles.size() == 1 && changedFiles[0] == "Jenkinsfile"){
    println "Only Jenkinsfile has changed... Skipping build..."
    currentBuild.getRawBuild().getExecutor().interrupt(Result.SUCCESS) // this skips your build prematurely and makes the rest of the stages green
    sleep(1) // you just need this
}else{
    println "There are other changes rather than only Jenkinsfile, build will proceed."
}
```

P.S. You have several ways to terminate the jobs earlier without failing the build, but this one is the cleanest in my experience, even though you need to allow some Admin Signatures Permission on Jenkins (I've seen it in another thread here some time ago, can't find it now though)

Comment: Your answer is clear. Can we make some changes like these, in first code if changeLogSet includes only JenkinsFile remove this changeLogSet fron buildChangeset. Then your second code block changeSet.size == 0 interrupt the build.