# Jenkins CI workflow with separate build and automated test both in source control

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, continuous-delivery, multibranch-pipeline

I am trying to improve our continuous integration process using Jenkins and our source control system (currently svn, but git soon).

Maybe I am thinking about this overly complicated, or maybe I have not yet seen the right hints.

The process I envisioned has three steps and associated roles:

1. one or more **developers** would do their job and ultimately submit the code changes for the actual software ("main software") as well as unit tests into source control (git, or something else). Jenkins shall build the software, run unit tests and perhaps some other steps (e.g. static code analysis). If none of this fails, the work of the developers is done. As part of the build, the build number is baked into the main software itself as part of the version number.
2. one or more **test engineers** will subsequently pickup the build and perform tests. Some of them may be manual, most of them are desired to be automated/scripted tests. *These shall ultimately be submitted into source control as well and be executed through the build server. However, this shall not trigger a new build of the main software* (since there is nothing changed). If none of this fails, the test engineers are done. Note that our automated tests currently take several hours to complete.
3. As a last step, a **project manager** authorizes release of the software, which executes whatever delivery/deployment steps are needed. Also, the source of the main software, unit tests, and automated test scripts, the jenkins build script - and ideally all build artifacts ("binaries") - are archived (tagged) in the source control system.

Ideally, developers are able to also manually trigger execution of the automated tests to "preview" the outcome of their build.

I have been unable to figure out how to do this with Jenkins and Git - or any other source control system.

Jenkin's pipelines seem to assume that all steps are carried out in sequence automatically. It also seems to assume that committing code into source control starts at the beginning (which I believe is not true if the commit was "merely" automated test scripts). Triggering an unnecessary build of the main software really hurts our process, as it basically invalidates and manual testing and documentation, as it results in a new build number baked into the software.

If my approach is so uncommon, please direct me how to do this correctly. Otherwise I would appreciate pointers how to get this done (conceptually).

Answer (score 0):

I will try to reply with some points. This is indeed conceptually approach as there are a lot of details and different approaches too, this is only one.

1. You need git :)
2. You need to setup a git branching strategy which will allow to have multiple developers to work simultaneously, pushing code and validating it agains the static code analysis. I would suggest that you start with [Git Flow](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), it is widely used and can be adapted to whatever reality you do have - you do not need to use it in its pure state, so give some thought how to adapt it. Fundamentally, it will allow for each feature to be tested. Then, each developer can merge it on the develop branch - from this point on, you have your features validated and you can start to deploy and test.
3. Have a look at [multibranch](https://plugins.jenkins.io/workflow-multibranch/) pipelines. This will allow you to test the several feature branches that you might have and to have different flows for the other branches - develop, release and master - depending on your deployment needs. So, when you have a merge on develop branch, you can trigger testing or just use it to run static code analysis.
4. To overcome the problem that you mention on your second point, there are ways to read your change sets on the pipeline, and in case the changes are only taken on testing scripts, you should not build your SW - check [here](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/217630098-How-to-access-Changelogs-in-a-Pipeline-Job-) how to read changes, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61417885/11073431) an example of how to read changes and also to prevent your pipeline to build all the stages according to the changes being pushed to git.
5. In case you still have manual testing taking place, pipelines are pausable which means that you can pause the pipeline asking for approval to proceed. Before approving, testers should do whatever they have to, and whenever they are ready to proceed, just approve the build to proceed for the next steps.
6. Regarding deployments authorization, it is done the same way that I mention on the last point, with the approvals, but in this case, you can specify which users/roles are allowed to approve that step.
7. Whatever you need to keep from your builds, Jenkins has an [archive artifacts](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/tests-and-artifacts/) utility. Let me just note that ideally you would look into a proper artefact repository such as [Nexus](https://www.sonatype.com/product-nexus-repository).
8. To trigger manually a set of tests... You can have a manually triggered job on Jenkins apart from your CI/CD pipeline, that will only execute the automated tests. You can even trigger this same job as one pipeline stage - [how to trigger another jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36306883/how-can-i-trigger-another-job-from-a-jenkins-pipeline-jenkinsfile-with-github)

Lastly let me say that the branching strategy is the starting point. 
Think on your big picture, what SDLC flows you need to have and setup those flows on your multibranch pipeline. Different git branches will facilitate whatever flows you need within the same Jenkinsfile - your pipeline definition. It really depends on how many environments you have to deploy to and what kind of steps you need.